How to convert T::AccountId to AccountId32?
How can I convert T::AccountId to AccountId32. who.into() don't work.
I am trying to do it in substrate pallet.
use sp_runtime::AccountId32;
use sp_io::hashing::blake2_256;


pub fn calculate_hash(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
    
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let mut current_hash: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];

            Self::update_hash_incrementally(current_hash, who.into());

            
            Ok(())
        }

    pub fn update_hash_incrementally(current_hash: [u8; 32], account_id: &AccountId32) -> [u8; 32] {
        let mut input_data = Vec::new();

        // Extend input data with the current hash and the new account ID
        input_data.extend_from_slice(&current_hash);
        input_data.extend_from_slice(account_id.as_ref());

        // Recalculate the hash with the new account ID
        blake2_256(&input_data)
    }

AccountId32 takes bytes
let account_id: AccountId32 = AccountId32::new(&account_id_bytes);
Not sure how to get the bytes [u8; 32] from who or T::AccountId

Are you trying to do this in a pallet or ..?
Please add more detail, thank you.

Ya, I am trying to do that in pallet.

Your answer is not entirely accurate.
Since AccountId is generic, you cannot guarantee it will always be 32 bytes long.
For instance, my chain utilizes AccountId20. The result of T::AccountId.encode() will not necessarily be 32 bytes in length.
However, if you state that you want the pallet to discard its generic nature, implying that it will always be employed in a AccountId32 chain, you can easily adjust your pallet's Config:
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config<AccountId = AccountId32> {
  ..
}

impl .. {
  fn calculate_hash(origin: ..) -> .. {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    let bytes32 = who.0;

    ..
  }
}

And this is safer. It won't compile if the AccountId isn't set as AccountId32.
In your code, if you attempt to use copy_from_slice to copy data from a source of length 20 to a target of length 32, the runtime will panic. You have to write more checking code like if encoded.len() != 32 { .. }.

Ok.  I will run the hashing offchain as zkp to check hash is correct. Is there generic for subxt? Subxt public key returns AccountId32 https://docs.rs/subxt-signer/0.38.0/subxt_signer/sr25519/struct.Keypair.html#method.public_key

The link you shared is about sr25519, it's always 32. And on client side I think you can easily define a struct to support generic account.

who.encode() does the job, it returns the bytes.
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn calculate_hash(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let current_hash: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
            let encode = who.clone().encode();

            <TestHash<T>>::put(encode.clone());

            let hash = Self::update_hash_incrementally(current_hash, who.encode());

            Self::deposit_event(Event::EncodeHash { encode, hash, account_id: who });

            // println!("hash {:?}", hash);

            Ok(())
        }

use scale_info::prelude::vec::Vec;
use sp_io::hashing::blake2_256;
use sp_runtime::AccountId32;

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn update_hash_incrementally(current_hash: [u8; 32], account_id: Vec<u8>) -> [u8; 32] {
        let mut input_data = Vec::new();

        // Extend input data with the current hash and the new account ID
        input_data.extend_from_slice(&current_hash);
        input_data.extend_from_slice(account_id.as_ref());

        // Recalculate the hash with the new account ID
        blake2_256(&input_data)
    }
}

The event:
EncodeHash { encode: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125], hash: [156, 44, 61, 111, 79, 136, 35, 154, 223, 190, 13, 94, 234, 224, 81, 59, 60, 251, 224, 205, 206, 87, 123, 179, 173, 105, 30, 79, 14, 111, 141, 89], account_id: AccountId32([212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125]) }
